# Right way of using asp-page and asp-route in asp.net core razor pages between _layout and index page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

Below is the file structure

[image]

I have default **Index page** under Pages folder, which has layout as **_LayoutHarman.cshmtl**

**Code : Pages/Shared/_LayoutHarman.chtml**

header menu : pages are in subfolder.ie category folder in this case

```
    <a asp-route-cat_slug="electronic" asp-page="./category/Index">Electronic</a>
    <a asp-route-cat_slug="beauty-care" asp-page="./category/index" >Beauty Care</a>
    <a asp-route-cat_slug="toy" asp-page="./category/index" >Toy</a>
```

footer menu : pages are on root folder

```
<a asp-page="./Contact" >Contact</a>
<a asp-page="./terms" >Terms</a>
<a asp-page="./privacy" >Privacy</a>
```

---

**Code : Pages/category/Index.cshtml**

```
    @page "{cat_slug?}/{pageIndex:int?}"
    @model bList.Pages.category.IndexModel
@{
 }
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination text-center">
        @if(Model.prev_no!=0){
            <li><a asp-page="category" asp-route-cat_slug="@Model.cat_url" asp-route-pageIndex="@Model.prev_no">  Previous</a></li>
        }
        @if (Model.no_more_record != "YES")
        {
          <li><a asp-page="category"  asp-route-cat_slug="@Model.cat_url" asp-route-pageIndex="@Model.next_no">Next</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here Next/ previous  button generate url as follow

https://localhost:8080/category/toy/1

https://localhost:8080/category/toy/2

https://localhost:8080/category/toy/3

respective on selected category

**Issue :** When i visit on **category page** and click on prev or next button and then try to click on link **Contact,Terms,Privacy** i.e (which is on _LayoutHarman.cshtml) or on header menu then href become  **blank**.

---

**Edited One:**

**Code: On _LayoutHarman.cshtml**

HeaderMenu:

```
<a  href="./category/toy" >toy</a>
```

Footer Menu

```
<a asp-page="./Contact" >Contact</a>
<a asp-page="./terms" >Terms</a>
```

**Code: On Category/Index.html page**

```
<a href="/category/@Model.cat_url/@Model.prev_no">Prev</a></li>
<a href="/category/@Model.cat_url/@Model.next_no">Next</a>
```

Now on **Next/ Prev** button click , header menu generates url as 
https://localhost:44382/category/toy/category/toy hence error page occurs. but for footer menu contact/term/privacy works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did reproduce your problem, you need to `delete the point(.)` in `asp-page` attribute in your `_LayoutHarman.cshmtl`.

Changed like this:

```
<a asp-route-cat_slug="electronic" asp-page="/category/Index">Electronic</a>
<a asp-route-cat_slug="beauty-care" asp-page="/category/index" >Beauty Care</a>
<a asp-route-cat_slug="toy" asp-page="/category/index" >Toy</a>

<a asp-page="/Contact" >Contact</a>
<a asp-page="/terms" >Terms</a>
<a asp-page="/privacy" >Privacy</a>
```

And you don't need to add  `asp-page="category"` in `Pages/category/Index.cshtml`, just delete this attribute in this page.

Here is my test result:

[image]

Comment: Hey you almost solved that problem. Now only 1 issue that is on click of header menu Toy and pagination next , next click , same toy header menu is not clickable, solution for that is i just added asp-route-pageIndex="1" to header menu and it works fine. Thank will mark your answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all this extra server side processing, asp-route-cat_slug asp-page?
Can't you just use plain old fashion HTML hyperlink? As for the dynamic parameters maybe you can set only them...

```
<a href="/category/toy/@Model.GetCategoryID">View category</a>
```

Just an idea to think on...

Cheers

Comment: Thanks i tried but still for header menu its not working

Comment: Could you post the modified code? Must not be a problem.